# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 Incorrect syntax near '-'

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure successfully. When I execute this procedure by passing parameters it throws the following exception:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near '-'

```
USE [master]
 GO

    DECLARE @return_value int

    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spJobsGet]
    @Email = N'peter_grout@outlook.com',
    @Password = N'password',
    @JobSheetID = 0,
    @PropertyID = 0,
    @DateFrom = 2014-06-20,
    @DateTo = 2014-07-20

    SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

    GO
```

I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: `@DateFrom = '2014-06-20',  @DateTo = '2014-07-20'` ??

Comment: These are the date i am passing as a parameter

Comment: Tried putting them in quotes?

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked like a charm. let me do your answer true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around your date string literals:

```
@DateFrom = '2014-06-20', 
@DateTo = '2014-07-20'
```

You should be aware that the format you are using can be ambiguous, a better option would be

```
@DateFrom = '20140620', 
@DateTo = '20140720'
```

which is always interpreted as YYYYMMDD.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx#UnseparatedStringFormat

Answer (score 0):

You should put parameters with datatype character or datetime or etc inside the quotes. So try this:

```
USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spJobsGet]
@Email = N'peter_grout@outlook.com',
@Password = N'password',
@JobSheetID = 0,
@PropertyID = 0,
@DateFrom = '2014-06-20',
@DateTo = '2014-07-20'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```